# Update selected row in ListBox - Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

I was using VB6 and here is the code which i used to update the row selected in List Box but unfortunately the code is updating all fields without met the criteria .

Any help to know what is the wrong with this code and any suggestion to solve this issue .

```
Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
        If List1.Selected(i) Then
        statement = "UPDATE Customer SET Flag = '1' "
        End If
con.Execute statement, , adCmdText
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code update all records because the criteria is missing.
The sql statement should be:

```
statement = "UPDATE Customer SET Flag = '1' WHERE <your_criteria> "
```

I can't suggest more because we don't know what should be your criteria. 
Only you say it.